# reset row number count in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like this

### file.txt

```
0   1   a
1   1   b
2   1   d
3   1   d
4   2   g
5   2   a
6   3   b
7   3   d
8   4   d
9   5   g
10   5   g
.
.
.
```

I want reset row number count to 0 in first column `$1` whenever value of field in second column `$2` changes, using awk or bash script.

### result

```
0   1   a
1   1   b
2   1   d
3   1   d
0   2   g
1   2   a
0   3   b
1   3   d
0   4   d
0   5   g
1   5   g
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you don't mind a bit of excess memory usage, and the second column is sorted, I think this is the most fun:

```
awk '{$1=a[$2]+++0;print}' input.txt
```

Comment: Oh, now I see it.  Wish I could +1 again.  Awesome.  :-)

Comment: This only works if the file is sorted on the second column. The count fails to reset if values of `$2` occur again later in the input.

Comment: @kevin.. the most beautiful short code i have ever seen :) thanks

Comment: Is the `+0` after the `++` for making sure `$1` gets assigned an int value? Do you even need that?

Comment: @doubleDown The first time any index is accessed, you will get the empty string (`""`), so that will be assigned to `$1` instead of `0`; `+0` makes it print `0`. If you wanted it 1-indexed, you could use just `++a[$2]`, without a `+0`.

Answer (score 6):

This awk one-liner seems to work for me:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk 'prev!=$2{first=0;prev=$2} {$1=first;first++} 1' input.txt
0 1 a
1 1 b
2 1 d
3 1 d
0 2 g
1 2 a
0 3 b
1 3 d
0 4 d
0 5 g
1 5 g
```

Let's break apart the script and see what it does.

- `prev!=$2 {first=0;prev=$2}` -- This is what resets your counter.  Since the initial state of `prev` is empty, we reset on the first line of input, which is fine.
- `{$1=first;first++}` -- For every line, set the first field, then increment variable we're using to set the first field.
- `1` -- this is awk short-hand for "print the line".  It's really a condition that always evaluates to "true", and when a condition/statement pair is missing a statement, the statement defaults to "print".

Pretty basic, really.

The one catch of course is that when you change the value of any field in awk, it rewrites the line using whatever field separators are set, which by default is just a space.  If you want to adjust this, you can set your `OFS` variable:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk -vOFS="   " 'p!=$2{f=0;p=$2}{$1=f;f++}1' input.txt | head -2
0   1   a
1   1   b
```

Salt to taste.

Comment: +1 Been looking for this kind of operation for a while, and it applies easily to any other kind of line numbering with a reset for each changing category. Great work.

Answer (score 2):

A pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution :

```
file="/PATH/TO/YOUR/OWN/INPUT/FILE"

count=0
old_trigger=0

while read a b c; do
    if ((b == old_trigger)); then
        echo "$((count++)) $b $c"
    else
        count=0
        echo "$((count++)) $b $c"
        old_trigger=$b
    fi

done < "$file"
```

This solution (IMHO) have the advantage of using a readable algorithm. I like what's other guys gives as answers, but that's not *that* comprehensive for beginners.

**NOTE**:

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for `let`, if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Comment: +1 - Nice.  Though you only need to set `old_trigger=$b` inside the `else` rather than every line ... and you COULD optimize this so that you only have one `echo` command.  Check out my `awk` solution for the logic.

Comment: Added **NOTE** explanations about `(( ... ))` clear, intuitive & nice syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -naE '
    $dec  =  $F[0] if defined $old and $F[1] != $old;
    $F[0] -= $dec;
    $old  =  $F[1];
    say join "\t", @F[0,1,2];'
```

`$dec` is subtracted from the first column each time. When the second column changes (its previous value is stored in `$old`), `$dec` increases to set the first column to zero again. The `defined` condition is needed for the first line to work.